# Using variables in -Include filter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a function which uses the [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) to work out the newest file within a folder. I need to find the latest incremental backup in a folder and script an EXE file to mount it. However, within this same folder there are multiple backup chains for all different servers, that is,

```
SERVER1_C_VOL_b001_i015.spi
SERVER2_D_VOL_b001_i189.spi
SERVER1_C_VOL_b002_i091.spi
SERVER1_E_VOL_b002_i891.spi (This is the newest file created)
```

I want only to look at `SERVER1`, look at only the `C_VOL` and look at only `b001` - nothing else.

I have all these separate components: the drive letter, the Server Name, the b00X number stored in an array.

How then can I go and use the `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Include` filter to only look at:

```
.spi
SERVER1
C_VOL
b001
```

Given I have all of these separate components in an array taken from a text file:

```
Get-Content .\PostBackupCheck-TextFile.txt | Select-Object -First $i { $a = $_ -split ' ' ; $locationArray += "$($a[0]):\$($a[1])\$($a[2])" ; $imageArray += "$($a[2])_$($a[3])_VOL_b00$($a[4])_i$($a[5]).spi" }
```

I go onto try and filter, and then I get stuck:

```
$latestIncremental = Get-ChildItem -Path ${shadowProtectDataLocation}\*.* -Include *.spi | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

I have the .spi filtered, but how can I also just include the C (for volume), the number for the b00x and the server name?

Answer (score 1):

> I  want only to look at SERVER1, look at only the C_VOL and look at only b001 - nothing else.

Is this meant to be inclusive or exclusive (the question is not 100% clear)?

Ie. is it `SERVER1` *and* `C_VOL` *and* …, or is it any file matching any one of them? Based on the final paragraph it seems you want the former.

I see two approaches, depending how closely the match criteria array matches the filename structuyre..

1. If your matching files have the a form that matches the filter criteria (eg. as in Q's example with same ordering of name components apart of extension first) then you can build that "like pattern" dynamically:

   ```
   $parts = … # the match parts array
   $pattern = (($parts | Select-Object -skip 1) -join '*') + $parts[0]
   $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $basePath -include $pattern | Sort-Object …
   ```
2. Apply each part of the pattern incrementally, again assuming the extension comes first in the file:

   ```
   $parts = … # the match parts array
   $potentialFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $basePath -include ('*' + $parts[0])
   $parts = $parts | Select-Object -skip 1
   foreach ($p in $parts) {
     $potentialFiles = $potentialFiles | Where-Objecft { $_.Name -like ('*' + $p + '*') }
   }
   # Now sort and select -first 1 to get single file (if any left to match)
   ```

Comment: Thanks Richard, however, the extension would never come first in the filename. It will always be SERVER_C_VOL_b001_*.spi. At the stage I'm at, I have SERVER_C_VOL_b001_*.spi and need to fill in the final * with a value which I will get the from the latest file I am searching for. And yes, it needs to match everything, up until the final _*.spi. Since the * in this instance, will contain a iXXX value where x is a number.

Comment: @TheD I'm assuming the extension comes first in the *input file* (obviously it doesn't come first in the file *name*).

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @TheD, sorry I misread the question slightly, took your contents of the array quote as a file you were reading into the array that contains the filter. I'll rework the answer.

Comment: When you mention $parts = … # the match parts array - what exactly do you mean? Sorry to keep hassling you!

Comment: @TheD "I have all these seperate components: […] stored in array."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19704/discussion-between-thed-and-richard)

Comment: @TheD sorry: too much else to get on with.